# How to prevent HTML elements from being pushed down the page

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, the text input and the buttons are supposed to be positioned 380px from the top but it's further down the page. I noticed if I remove the image it's positioned in the right place or closer to it, I haven't pulled out a ruler yet. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
<div style="position:relative;width:800px;height:792px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;margin:0 auto;left:8px;top:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <img name="Image712" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" style="position:relative;display:block;margin:0 auto;top:217px;width:269px;height:95px;" />
    <div name="HGroup714" style="position:relative;display:block;margin:0 auto;top:380px;width:220px;height:23px;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;padding-right:2px">
            <input name="Button715" type="button" style="position:relative;vertical-align:middle;width:101px;height:21px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;" class="buttonSkin" value="Google Search" />
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <input name="Button718" type="button" style="position:relative;vertical-align:middle;width:113px;height:21px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;" class="buttonSkin" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="TextInput721" type="input" style="position:relative;display:block;margin:0 auto;top:330px;width:50%;height:22px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:0;border:1px solid #696969;" />
</div>


<style>
    *,
    *: before, *: after {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>

<style>
    *,
    *: before, *: after {
        outline: 1px dotted red;
    }
</style>
```

UPDATE: I know it's inline CSS. Please ignore that for now.

Link to live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hxS9E/) (thanks Mr Alien).

Comment: i think you are looking for `position: fixed` to keep it fixed, relative to the window rather than relative to it's parent object. This way scrolling leaves it where you expect it to be.

Comment: This is a positioning disaster, anyways http://jsfiddle.net/hxS9E/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that as the image is a relative positioned element, the 'top' css tag applied to the 'HGroup714; element is from the bottom of this image, therefore the height of the image moves it down the page. If you wanted this to not affect the positioning of the lower elements you could simply remove the 95px height of the image from the 'top' tag on the Hgroup element.

Any relative positioning will cause your elements to be positioned relative to each other, so you much take them out of the page flow by using position:absolute, and removing any relative positioning from parent elements.

Suggestions to use position:fixed; would only work if the page were never to be scrolled - fixed positioning fixes it within the browser window, and scrolling keeps it at that same positioning, whereas absolute is not reliant on the position of other elements, but maintains it's place in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I specify absolute position it prevents horizontal centering from working.

Comment: Adding left:0; and right:0; on the absolute positioned element given that you have 'margin:0 auto;' set should fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using position relative, which places you relative towards the location where you should be rendered, you want to use position absolute. Absolute is rendered in relation to it's parent, which is what you're actually looking for.

Position fixed does the same thing as absolute, except the 'parent' is the browser window.

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/fr6AY/1/

```
position:absolute;
margin:0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it 380px from the top of the window (**not the page**), you are looking for `position: fixed`.

If you want it 380px from the **top of the page**, try using `position: absolute` in the `HGroup714` element.

Comment: If I use absolute or fixed position I lose centering. See the example, http://jsfiddle.net/hxS9E/.

Comment: You don't, __if__ you change the CSS accordingly. Check my example: http://jsfiddle.net/K42C5/1/